# Ошибка при деплое проекта в Heroku

Tags: heroku

Пытаюсь залить проект на Heroku. Действую по документации https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-gradle-on-heroku
На этапе деплоя получаю ошибку

```
Перечисление объектов: 8588, готово.
Подсчет объектов: 100% (8588/8588), готово.
При сжатии изменений используется до 4 потоков
Сжатие объектов: 100% (5303/5303), готово.
Запись объектов: 100% (8588/8588), 11.57 MiB | 533.00 KiB/s, готово.
Всего 8588 (изменения 2216), повторно использовано 8588 (изменения 2216)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting Django==3.0.8
remote:          Downloading Django-3.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting requests==2.22.0
remote:          Downloading requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement s (from -r /tmp/build_8edef679/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for s (from -r /tmp/build_8edef679/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to thawing-taiga-04218.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/thawing-taiga-04218.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «https://git.heroku.com/thawing-taiga-04218.git»
```

Чем это вызвано и что предпринять для исправления положения?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в лишней строчке с буквой s в requirements.txt
После обновления репозитория без этой строки все задеплоилось